# How to get Next/Previous Post titles under WP_Query loop?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a custom post type named "videos" for Wordpress project. Under that I have created a taxonomy named 'video-categories'. The purpose was to create a page where the Video will be shown on single-videos.php page and then there needed a loop below the Video showing list of all Videos. Now here is where I needed help. I built the Loop fine using this code

```
<?php
$args = array( 
    'post_type' => 'videos', 
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'video-categories',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $category_id
        )
    )
);
?>
<?php   $loop = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php   if($loop) :?>
<?php   while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();?>

... things to do inside the loop ...

<?php   endwhile; ?>
<?php   endif;?>
<?php   wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

The `$category_id` variable holds `video-category` ID of the current post. This loop lists all Videos fine but what I need to do is, I want to put a link for Next and Previous posts under **Same term** which is here **$category_id**

So generally, I am trying to find a way to get the next and previous posts under `WP_Query`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Wordpress built in functions

for a list of next posts (new page)

```
next_posts_link()
```

Previous posts (new page)

```
previous_posts_link()
```

For single post pages

```
next_post_link()
```

and

```
previous_post_link()
```

Both can be used on any single post page, doesn't matter how you pulled the post

Comment: I know about this already and tried. This does not list next and previous posts of same Term under Taxonomy.

Comment: They do work if you tweak your code little bit, look at this similar case http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364488/wordpress-pagination-next-posts-link-on-custom-wp-query-not-showing

Answer (score -1):

I actually made a simple function where you can add your custom query object as a parameter, like this: keha76_print_pagination( $loop ); It's using the paginate_links function to build the pagination output.

https://gist.github.com/keha76/7096613

Comment: That link is broken.

Comment: That link is broken.