# Custom page template displaying loop of posts (Wordpress queries)

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, loops

This is not the first time i'm stuck on this with Wordpress...
Here's the thing :  I would like to have a

- a "portfolio" page (set as front page) displaying the last 16 posts having the tag *portfolio*
- a "blog" page displaying the last XX (WP default) posts.

I read a lot about queries, front page, home, etc, and my conclusion is that I should

- build two pages
- assign a different template to each of them, with a custom design
- NOT make a [custom query in my template](https://gist.github.com/krogsgard/5915715#file-wp-query-the-right-way-php) for this; since it will
  break the pagination : [next_posts_link()](http://codex.wordpress.org/next_posts_link), for example, will show
  nothing since it is based on the main query, not the custom query.

> It is strongly recommended that you use the **pre_get_posts** filter
>   instead **query_posts()**, and alter the main query by checking is_main_query

So, [as recommanded in the codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts), I decided to filter pre_get_posts in functions.php rather than to use wp_query(...) directly in the portfolio template.

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'cargo_portfolio' );
```

Then I set up some conditions to check I'm on the right page :

```
function cargo_portfolio( $query ) {
    if (!$query->is_main_query() ) return;
    if ( $query->get( 'page_id' ) && ( $query->get( 'page_id' ) == 128 )){ //128 is my portfolio page
        //edit query here
        }
}
```

I don't want to use a static number (128), so I found this instead (code for the portfolio/front page)

```
function cargo_portfolio( $query ) {
    if (!$query->is_main_query() ) return;
    //check is static home page, since is_front_page() is not working yet at this level
    if ( $query->get( 'page_id' ) && ( $query->get( 'page_id' ) == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) )){ 
        //edit query here
        }
}
```

And I start to edit the query with this code :

```
$query->set( 'page_id', null );
$query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
$query->set( 'tag', 'portfolio' );
$query->set( 'showposts', 16 );
```

So I end up with this function :

```
function cargo_portfolio( $query ) {
    if (!$query->is_main_query() ) return;
    //check is static home page, since is_front_page() is not working yet at this level
    if ( $query->get( 'page_id' ) && ( $query->get( 'page_id' ) == get_option( 'page_on_front' ) )){ 
    $query->set( 'page_id', null );
    $query->set( 'post_type', 'post' );
    $query->set( 'tag', 'portfolio' );
    $query->set( 'showposts', 16 );
    }
}
```

WELL. Thanks for reading... :)

The problem here, is that I unset the **page_id** and change the **post_type** vars (since I want to fetch posts), and that it breaks the query.  Now I'm landing on a 404 page.

Does anyone have a good solution to achieve this ?  Before, I was using [The Loops plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-loops/), but it has not been updated since 2 years and is broken. + : I'm sure there should be a simple way to do this.

Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up by using a custom query directly in the template.

It IS possible to use  pagination **functions get_next_posts()** and **get_previous_posts()** by adding a query parameter to it, see here :

[Wordpress pagination (next_posts_link) on custom wp_query not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364488/wordpress-pagination-next-posts-link-on-custom-wp-query-not-showing).

Thanks !