# Pagination for custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

I'm trying to get pagination for a custom post type. I don't know what's wrong with the code but it doesn't work. This is what I have done so far:

```
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=medios-link&order=DESC&posts_per_page=4' ); ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div><?php the_field('texto_adicional') ?></div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <div class="nav-posts">
        <div class="prev-post">
           <?php  next_posts_link( '&lt; <br/>Previous posts',$query) ?>
        </div>
        <div class="next-post">
            <?php previous_posts_link( '&gt; <br/>Next posts' ) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: How it does not work ? Errors ? What is the desired behaviour ? What is the output html ?

Comment: It does not work meaning I dont get any links for pagination. No console errors. I hope you can help me out since you seem very interested in this question

Comment: I'm not a regular wordpress user, but I see you use once `$query->the_post();` and then just `the_field('texto_adicional')`... Can you try with `$query->the_field('texto_adicional')` ?

Comment: Well that is to get the info from the custom post type. That is working good. The problem is that the functions `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` don't output the pagination.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364488/wordpress-pagination-next-posts-link-on-custom-wp-query-not-showing

Comment: thanks Brewal, will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
    $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=product&order=DESC&posts_per_page=2&paged=' . $paged ); ?>
<?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <div><?php //the_field('texto_adicional') 
        the_title(); ?></div>
<?php endwhile;?>
 <div class="nav-posts">
    <div class="prev-post">
               <?php  next_posts_link( '&lt; <br/>Previous posts',$query->max_num_pages ) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="next-post">
                <?php previous_posts_link( '&gt; <br/>Next posts' ) ?>
    </div>
</div>
```