# Why is next_post_link() not working with WP_Query?

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

Been researching a pagination issue I am having with WordPress.  My `page-foobar.php` file is:

```
<?php
// the query
$foobar_args = array( 'post_type' => 'foobar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, );
$foo_query = new WP_Query( $foobar_args );
if ( $foo_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $foo_query->have_posts() ) : $foo_query->the_post();?>
        // code
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>                           
    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no foobar posts at this time.', 'theme' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I added:

```
<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer',$foo_query->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;',$foo_query->max_num_pages); ?>
</nav>
```

after referencing [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14595709/pagination-on-custom-post-wp-query/18325002#18325002) after the `endif;`:

The link shows in the url as `site/foobar/page/2/` but displays the 404 page.  After some further research I ran across an article that mentioned the `page-foobar.php` and `posttype-foobar.php` [names can clash](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/pagination-with-custom-post-type-listing#post-1637753) so to rename one of them.  I renamed `posttype-foobar2.php`, changed my `functions.php`, tested and still get sent to the 404 page with the correct URL.  Another article mentioned that you must use `wp_query()` so I changed my `page-foobar.php` to:

```
<?php
// the query
$foobar_args = array( 'post_type' => 'foobar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => true, );
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $foobar_args );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
        // code
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>                           
    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no foobar posts at this time.', 'theme' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

pagination:

```
<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
</nav>
```

I did test this by adding this before `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` and after `<?php endwhile; ?>`:

```
<nav>
    <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
    <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
</nav>
```

tested and I still get sent to a 404 page.  When I change `next_posts_link()` to `<?php var_dump(next_posts_link('&laquo; Older Entries', $wp_query->max_num_pages)); ?>` it returns `NULL`.  If I change `next_posts_link()` to `get_next_posts_link()` I get `string(99)`.  What am I doing wrong with my pagination?

Further Referenced:

- [Wordpress pagination (next_posts_link) on custom wp_query not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364488/wordpress-pagination-next-posts-link-on-custom-wp-query-not-showing)
- [next_posts_link 404 error](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/next_posts_link-404-error)
- [WP_Query and next_posts_link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20424/wp-query-and-next-posts-link)

How can I properly get my pagination to go to the next page?

Comment: Add `nav` before `wp_reset_postdata` and try

Comment: I did try that and still get the error.  I will edit my question

Comment: Those functions need to happen within The Loop (i.e. where `// code` is).

Comment: @mevius If I were to do that it would place a `nav` below every post on the page.  Unless you mean something I am not seeing post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some further research I ran across the solution to my problem and I hope it can help someone else.  The answer submitted by [Sindhu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643461/why-is-next-post-link-not-working-with-wp-query/32644294#32644294) does have merit in respect to the addition of:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

and the modification to the arguments:

```
$foobar_args = array( 'post_type' => 'foobar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged' => $paged);
```

Codex for [`get_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var).  After making this additional change it still didn't work so I started testing my Permalinks.  When I ran the code under `Default` the pagination worked.  When I changed to `Post name` and saved twice it still didn't work.  After browsing I decided to search for `custom post type giving 404 error` and I ran across "[Fixing Custom Post Type 404 Errors In WordPress](http://www.wpexplorer.com/post-type-404-error/)" which mentioned I could be creating a double slug.  After review I was in fact doing so and WordPress was clashing with the double slug.  I decided to changed my `posttype-foobar.php` to `posttype-foobar_t.php` and updated my functions.php file. Instead of modifying the database on my localhost to fix the slug issue I decided to install a clean installation with the modified changes and it works.

I would also like to point out some of my findings in regards to a large majority of posts mentioned you have to call the query as `$wp_query = new WP_Query( $foobar_args );`.

Answer (score 2):

```
// the query
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$foobar_args = array( 'post_type' => 'foobar', 'posts_per_page' => 4, 'paged' => $paged);
$wp_query = new WP_Query( $foobar_args );
if ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $wp_query->have_posts() ) : $wp_query->the_post();?>
          <?php the_title(); echo "<br/>"; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <nav>
      <?php previous_posts_link('&laquo; Newer',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
      <?php next_posts_link('Older &raquo;',$wp_query->max_num_pages); ?>
    </nav>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>                           
    <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no foobar posts at this time.', 'theme' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```